# Not able to perform segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

hi the session block works fine but when I am trying to move to next Viewcontroller I get thread1:Signal SIGABRT ..Actually I am trying to get request from server and use the reply to perform the following codes

```
    - (IBAction)submitb:(id)sender{
    if(_otptf.text==self.otpStr && _otptf.text>0){
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"phone=%@",self.stri1];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    //Next up, we read the postData's length, so we can pass it along in the request.
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    // Now that we have what we'd like to post, we can create an NSMutableURLRequest, and include our postData
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test.kre8tives.com/barebon/customer_checkapi.php"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSLog(@"the data Details is %@", post);
          //   And finally, we can send our request, and read the reply by creating a new NSURLSession:
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    static NSURLSession* sharedSessionMainQueue = nil;
    if(!sharedSessionMainQueue){
        sharedSessionMainQueue = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:nil delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
    }

    [[sharedSessionMainQueue dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; // this is json string
    //  NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error]; // you need to convert to dictionary object
        NSLog(@"Req cust:%@",requestReply);
        NSLog(@"requestReply cust: %@", jsonDict);
        self.tmpv1=[jsonDict valueForKey:@"success"] ;
        self.strv1=self.tmpv1;
        NSLog(@"tmp storage inside block:%@",self.tmpv1);
        if (!error) {
            if([self.tmpv1 isEqualToString:@"%@"],"0"){
                          [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"x2" sender:self];
                //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"x2" sender:self];
                }
            if([self.tmpv1 isEqualToString:@"%@"],"1"){
                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"b2" sender:self];
                }
        }
    }] resume];
   // [self navi];

}
else{
/* what ever */
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Inputs Found or Incorrect Otp!!"
                                                message:@"Please check your input!!."
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
    }
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(nullable      id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"x2"])
   {
    ProfileViewController *loadCtr = (ProfileViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    //loadCtr.mobilestrp = self.stri1;
}

else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"b2"])
{

}

}
```

this is my log

```
2017-06-05 12:14:32.884 MenuBar[1496:103465] the data Details is phone=9047038606
2017-06-05 12:14:33.726 MenuBar[1496:103531] requestReply: {
    otp = 828712;
    success = 1;
}
2017-06-05 12:14:33.727 MenuBar[1496:103531] tmp storage inside block:828712
2017-06-05 12:14:33.728 MenuBar[1496:103531]  storage:828712
2017-06-05 12:14:33.729 MenuBar[1496:103531] tmp storage:828712
2017-06-05 12:14:33.738 MenuBar[1496:103465] 9047038606
2017-06-05 12:14:45.069 MenuBar[1496:103465] the data Details is phone=9047038606 
2017-06-05 12:14:49.919 MenuBar[1496:103465] Req cust:{"success":0}
2017-06-05 12:14:52.373 MenuBar[1496:103465] requestReply cust: {
    success = 0;
}
2017-06-05 12:14:52.715 MenuBar[1496:103465] tmp storage inside block:0
2017-06-05 12:28:08.486 MenuBar[1520:108818] -[WelcomeViewController setCustid:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff98f908790
2017-06-05 12:28:08.491 MenuBar[1520:108818] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-   [WelcomeViewController setCustid:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance   0x7ff98f908790'
    *** First throw call stack:
   (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ba31b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b126141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation
```

thanks in advance for the suggestions!!

Comment: `uodateb` outlet is connect to some UI element, but not declared in ViewController file. There are lots of SO posts already regarding this, you should've checked for "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key" search term

Comment: I don't have an ui element like that I have deleted that element@Mr.Bista and yes I have gone through older questions I cudnt get any answer so I posted a new one

Comment: have you deleted it from xib, with right-click option?

Comment: Check you IBOutlet connection its not proper. @akshay

Comment: I think some IBAction is missing. `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: okay thanks let me check it!!

Comment: what is custId?

Comment: put a check `if(segue.identifier is equaltoString = @"ProfileViewControllerSegueIdentifier"){//Your segue code here}` because  on click it is trying to segue to your `WelcomeViewController`.

Comment: i think ProfileViewController's segue identifier conflict with WelcomeViewController's identifier .

Comment: identifiers are different one is b2 another is x2@KKRocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not checking the **segue identifier** in `prepareForSegue` method.

Check it like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(nullable    id)sender{
  if([segue.identifier isEqulaToString: @"x2"]){
    //x2 view controller settings 
  }
  else if([segue.identifier isEqulaToString: @"b2"]){
    //b2 view controller settings 
  }
}
```

With this, you can have specific view controller and it's properties to set.

Comment: is my if statement correct ??? coz it doesn't perform both the segues @DashAndRest

Comment: you can use `isEqualToString` method to check string equality, better you debug your code with break points and check if any of `x2` or `b2` is getting performed or not

Comment: yes I did that using break points it jus reads all the code from starting of if (!error) till end and suddenly it performs b2 at times and give thread1 error again

Comment: 2017-06-05 13:07:52.174 MenuBar[1841:134548] tmp storage inside block:0
2017-06-05 13:07:58.738 MenuBar[1841:134548] -[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000003
2017-06-05 13:07:58.741 MenuBar[1841:134548] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000003'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: This is another error says you are calling isEqualToString method on number. Better you edit your question with updated code

Comment: `if([self.tmpv1 isEqualToString:@"%@"],"0")` this is wrong. If `self.tmpv1` is `NSString` variable then you have to check like `if([self.tmpv1 isEqualToString:@"0"])`, Whats is `self.tmpv1`?

Comment: it is the reply from server which can be one or zero

Comment: If you have declared `int tmpv1;` then simply do `if (self.tmpv1 == 0)`, if not then show your variable declaration code.

Comment: everything is string as server replies in json so I declared those in nsstring

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145857/discussion-between-akshay-and-dashandrest).

Answer (score 2):

**A segue** defines a transition between two view controllers. While in your case the segue is presenting `WelcomeViewController` which have no property `custid`, so it is better to keep check using `segue identifier`.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

       if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_IDENTIFER"]) {
           //YOUR Code Here
           ProfileViewController *loadCtr = (ProfileViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
           loadCtr.custid =self.tmpv1;
           loadCtr.mobilestrp = self.stri1;

       }
}
```

**Note:** Make sure that the **starting point**(initiates the segue) and **ending point**(you want to display) of segues are correct. Moreover always use  unique identifier for segue on your Storyborad.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**Solution 1**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ProfileViewController's identifier"])
    {
         ProfileViewController *loadCtr = (ProfileViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
             loadCtr.custid =self.tmpv1;
             loadCtr.mobilestrp = self.stri1;
    }

    else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"another identifier"])
    {

    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

Check both viewcontroller's assigned segue identifier and if both are same then assign different identifier .

Answer (score -1):

Check your IBActions and variables in profileViewController whether it has link to your file or not. That is your **reference outlet**.